# Why is Magento's "Tier Price" attribute of the type "text"?

Tags: magento

I have an extension that allows an admin to select attributes from a list to show in tabs on the detail page on the frontend.

The list of attributes is filtered by the type "text" and "textarea". The values of these attributes are then echoed in the tabs.

However, I just noticed that both the "Tier Price" and "Group Price" attributes show in the list. On checking those 2 attributes, I found that they are indeed of the "text" type:

[image: Tier attribute]

I'm wondering why that is, considering the input for them is most definitely not a simple text box:

[image: admin input]

...and they in fact output an array.